# Adding files to hostgator site directory

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor

So, guys, I need help.

Basically, I've created a site using the Word Press plugin inside Hostgator. So far so good.

There is a page on my site that has a form so the users can submit their names and emails so they are able to download a free ebook. Since I`m using elementor for WordPress and the form widget is only available with elementor pro, I've inserted the form using the HTML widget, with a js script inside the HTML to handle the data and send them to a real-time database on Firebase.

The point is, to send the data to Firebase, I need to initialize the Firebase app using my project config object inside the js script, which contains my API, and that should not be available to anyone who simply tries to inspect the code through chrome tools, for example.

A workaround would be to put the Firebase project config object in a separate locked file inside the site directory so I can simply import it within my script inside the HTML widget and initialize the Firebase app with the project config, without exposing my API and project config object to everyone.

So, is there a way to do this? Sorry if I did not make myself clear!

Comment: Your work-around still sends the API key to the client. Instead, end the details to the hosting server and have that pass the information on to Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Firebase, you may as well use [CloudFunctions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions), and create a function that works as an intermediary that handles different requests from the client side.

This method will keep the client side code as simple as just sending the form.

Comment: Thought about that, problem is as far as I know the function feature is paid.